# Why don't my CSS text color transitions work on input element placeholders in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, transition

Is it possible to apply a transition to the text color of the Firefox `placeholder` element?

This code produces a nice fade effect on webkit browsers but just changes the placeholder text from black to grey with no transition on Firefox. (Tested on v22 and v23.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H3J9t/

```
<style>

::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: inherit; opacity: 1; font-weight: normal !important; -webkit-transition: color 0.3s; transition: color 0.3s; /* WebKit */ }
:-moz-placeholder { color: inherit; opacity: 1; font-weight: normal !important; -moz-transition: color 0.3s; transition: color 0.3s; /* Firefox 4 to 18 */ }
::-moz-placeholder { color: inherit; opacity: 1; font-weight: normal !important; -moz-transition: color 0.3s; transition: color 0.3s; /* Firefox 19+ */ }
:-ms-input-placeholder { color: inherit; opacity: 1; font-weight: normal !important; -ms-transition: color 0.3s; transition: color 0.3s; /* Internet Explorer 10+ */ }

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: rgb(80%, 80%, 80%); /* WebKit */ }
:focus:-moz-placeholder { color: rgb(80%, 80%, 80%); /* Firefox 4 to 18 */ }
:focus::-moz-placeholder { color: rgb(80%, 80%, 80%); /* Firefox 19+ */ }
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color: rgb(80%, 80%, 80%); /* Internet Explorer 10+ */ }

input { width: 100%; display: bock; font-size: 18pt; }

</style>

<input width="100%" placeholder="The color should change on focus, but it should be a 300ms transition, not a jarring change." >
```

Comment: I would like to say no. Even if you get it to work on the current firefox version this kind of feature is likely going to have major cross-platform issues. You could do a psuedo-placeholder. By actually manipulating the value and adding a class if its placeholder or not, but this requires some javascript.

Comment: Works for me in chrome, I just think it's not really well supported

Comment: It's almost 2024, but placeholder text color transitions still don't work in Firefox (v115, v119). Firefox dev team, please fix this already.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if we can use `:focus` on placeholder but anyway, he is not at the good place.

To respect CSS it is everytime `element:pseudo-element` so you have to write it like this

::-webkit-placeholder:focus {...}

After, rgb color are 0 to 255 (int), not percent (I never try but it is maybe your problem)