# CSS3 Placeholder hover Transition not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css

For some reason I cant seems to get placeholder transitions to work with Firefox. Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/manifestinteractive/pen/viaAK) example. This example has placeholder transitions for both `:hover` and `:focus`. Both work with Chrome, neither work with Firefox.

Comment: @StephenThomas That solution does not work for me. Even the jsfiddle example in the answer is not working. There is no transition when viewed in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a problem other than needing [the `-moz` prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility).  Try:

```
h1 {
  color: #300;
  -moz-transition: color 2s;
  -webkit-transition: color 2s;
  -o-transition: color 2s;
  -ms-transition: color 2s;
  -transition: color 2s;
}
h1:hover {
  color: #933;
}
```

On the other hand, your situation may be related to [an actual bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289), too.

Comment: The -moz prefix is already applied. Check out the CodePen and you'll see. Unless some how I used it incorrectly but I don't think so.

Comment: Right you are, my mistake; I missed the link.  It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178660/why-dont-my-css-text-color-transitions-work-on-input-element-placeholders-in-fi) hit the same sort of stumbling block.  Trying a few variations that are claimed to work, I can't do any better than an instant switch.

Comment: Cool thanks for trying. It seems strange that so many resources say this should work but it doesn't.